# Hudson : Scheduling a build without a tag and generate a report

Tags: linux, cygwin, cross-platform, hudson, wce

How can I schedule a build without tag over Windows, Linux and WCE in Hudson using a shell script and generate a report that will be sent to a specified server?

And so the conditions are :

**1.** How can I create the build without creating a new tag?

**2.** How is it possible to excute .sh over windows and WCE (Windows Mobile), is it simply by going through Cygwin? Moreover, having a cross-platform (3 platforms) build does it mean that I must run the build 3 times?

**3.** How to generate a report and save it in a directory of a server that I'm authorized to access to?

I know that I asked many questions at once. It is because this is my first use of Hudson and these are kind of details. Moreover, I don't want to make a mistake by creating new tags during my tests. The 1st and 3rd questions are the most important. If anyone gives me the right answer to them, I'll choose it as the right answer.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

first, people nowadays mostly use jenkins instead of hudson (open source, better support)

1. build can be started manually in hudson / jenkins, just click the green arrow. It will create a new build but won't change your repository (unless the last step of your build is creating a tag, in that case, just remove that step for testing)
2. Usually, .sh scripts run in shell excecutables (ash, sh, bash, csh...) and are not supported of the shell on windows. You'll have to go through cygwin or have a platform specific build command
3. kind of not clear for me. If you use jenkins to build a matric build (with the matrix axis being your target platform), you'll have automatically a nice report in jenkins itself (status of each build). You can keep artifacts (use post-build action : archive the artifacts) or use another plugin to publish the file you like (exemple : ftp reporting)

Sorry not being able to be more precise, that's how far I understand your questions.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. I need to clarify things. 1st : "unless the last step of your build is creating a tag", would this be an option chosen in the job form at Hudson level, or an instruction written in the shell script?